# TypeError when using AWS S3 Bucket with Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm brand new to Django and AWS S3 and seem to have hit a wall. This is all on localhost at the moment. I'm trying to add a new product through my own admin app for a Art Gallery website i'm working on, all worked fine originally when adding a product, but since using AWS S3 i receive the following TypeError:

[image]

[image]

The error states that it's expecting *"...a string or bytes-like object."* and refers to the following lines of code in both my **mixins.py** and my staff **views.py**

**mixins.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class StaffUserMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            return redirect("home")
        return super(StaffUserMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py:**

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, StaffUserMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'staff/product_create.html'
    form_class = ProductForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("staff:product-list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

As I stated at the start i'm very new to both Django and AWS S3, so if this is just a schoolboy error, please forgive me but any help would be fantastic. And if any additional info is needed i'll be happy to provide. Thanks!

Comment: you could use `print(...)` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables and what you get from functions - ie. what you get from `super(...).dispatch(...)`. You can also use `print()` to better recognize which line is working and which makes problem - ie. `print("before super dispatch")` It is called `"print debuging"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to write some lines in your `settings.py` file in order to get `django-storages` to work.

Those lines are:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
```

and you need to identify those variables in your `.bash_profile` file (if you are on mac) so that they are not committed to your version control system for security reasons.

You need to follow this syntax:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="YOUR_ID" **(NO SPACES)**
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
export AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME="YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"
```

and then you need to provide Heroku (on which I encountered this error) with this data by using `configVars`.

In your Terminal/CommandLine:

```
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="YOUR_ID"
heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
heroku config:set AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME="YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"
```

**Make sure to use double-quotes!**